# Unsuccesfully trying hyphenate text in Sencha panels

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2, hyphenation

I'm working on an ebook that has its pages spread in panels in Sencha Touch 2 and having a bad time trying to hyphenate the paragraphs in the panels. I've tried Hyphenator.js and CSS3 hyphenation without any luck. Same code in html outside the Sencha framework hyphenates successfully. Any clues? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you provide some code, or even better a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) too.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, fractious. It was actually my fault, since the Hyphenator.js operates based on the LANG tag in the html head. Since I changed that tag according to the script everything worked as expected. Just don't know what to do with this thread, if I delete or respond myself. Accepting advices regarding that.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it sorted. If you post an answer to your own question detailing what you did to fix the problem, others can learn from it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Hyphenator.js works fine inside the Sencha panels. The problem was that the LANG tag in the head section of my index.html was not set in the same languages of the hyphenator script I was linking. Once I resolved that problem, words in the panel html got hyphenated.